# How to show videos in gridview ! (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, flutter-video-player

I am getting the video files from filepicker package now i want to show the videos on gridview when clicked on them video should be played (similar to gallery)

Answer (score 0):

Found answer my self first I generated the thumbnail of the video by thumbnail package(https://pub.dev/packages/video_thumbnail) from then saved created a model of thumbnail path and video path saved the path of both and accessed them :)